# Is it possible to write data directly from a mobile to a PC through the mobile's SD card slot?

Tags: usb, communication, camera, sd-card

I have to questions:
-Is it possible to write data directly from GoPro to a Raspberry Pi through the GoPro's SD card slot?
-How does Micro SD card function?

I would like to use my GoPro (hero 1) as a webcam, but unfortunately, I can't use it's USB port to stream to the RPi.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. Both the RPi and the GoPro will attempt to access to the SD card or interface at the same time, and could cause damage to each other.

The closest you can come is:

1. A sd to wifi card, like the EyeFi or Flash Air. You won't be able to **stream live video** but can wirelessly upload a video **file**.
2. A UVC compatible video capture device. UVC is the USB Video Class, basically a generic driverless video & audio input card. The GoPro's composite output will connect to it. (No you can't use the RPI's composite output as an input). A generic usb webcam would be cheaper.
3. Use an RPi camera module. Also cheap.

Comment: I missed suggesting the USB webcam. That would provide a good array of cost and resolution options. Reusing the GoPro for this is definitely suboptimal.

Comment: Or use a GoPro with wifi built in, or with a wifi bacpac add-on. Depends on just what model GoPro you have.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot expect to attach a device to the SD card slot and expect to be able to implement streaming video from the GoPro. You likely need to find a different device to act as the video source for the RPi.

For the older GoPro devices, searching the internet indicates that the only way to get video onto a computer is to use an analog or digital video capture card.